# Populate a multiple select based on choice of other multiple select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 multiple select menus in my main admin area, one for users of a page and one for admins of a page.

I want it to automatically select the same option in the users menu that is selected in the admin menu, but not vice versa.

This is the code I've tried but it just breaks the userOf menu.

```
<select multiple id="userOf">
    <option value="1">Page 1</option>
    <option value="2">Page 2</option>
    <option value="3">Page 3</option>
    <option value="4">Page 4</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<select multiple id="adminOf">
    <option value="1">Page 1</option>
    <option value="2">Page 2</option>
    <option value="3">Page 3</option>
    <option value="4">Page 4</option>
</select>



<script type="text/javascript">
$("#adminOf").change(function() {
    var selected=[];
    var value;
    $("#adminOf option:selected").each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).attr("value"))
    });

    $("#userOf option").each(function() {
        value=$(this).val();
        if($.inArray(value, selected)){
            $(this).attr("selected","selected");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Thanks;

Comment: `$.inArray()` returns the index of the matching item, or -1 if it's not found. -1 is 'truthy' in a conditional like that.  Check for `!= -1` and it'll behave more like you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
var $admins = $("#adminOf");
var $users = $("#userOf");
$admins.change(function(e) {
    $admins.find("option").each(function(i,el){
        var isSelected = this.selected,
            index = i;

        $users.find("option").each(function(i){
            if(index == i){
                this.selected = isSelected;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4t2ugn1k/

Answer (score 0):

I've tested below code in `IE9`. It is working fine. It'll replicate selection of `adminOf`  to `userOf`

```
 $("#adminOf").click(function () {
        var selected = [];
        var value;
        $("#userOf").val([]); //unselect all the elements

        $("#adminOf option:selected").each(function () {
            var valAdmin = $(this).attr("value");
            $("#userOf option").each(function () {
                var valUser = $(this).attr("value");
                if (valAdmin === valUser) {
                    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```